# "Native Kubernetes" sample in Flink documentation fails. JobManager Web Interface is wrongly generated. [Flink 1.14.4]

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I am getting the following error when I try to execute sample at [Flink documentation - Native Kubernetes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/).

I have succedded to execute the first command in documentation by adding some extra parameters with the help of [this post](https://cloudolife.com/2020/12/12/Cloud-Native/BIg-Data/Flink/Deploy-a-Apache-Flink-session-cluster-natively-on-Kubernetes-K8S/).

```
user@local:~/flink-1.14.4$ ./bin/kubernetes-session.sh \
-Dkubernetes.cluster-id=dproc-example-flink-cluster-id \
-Dtaskmanager.memory.process.size=4096m \
-Dkubernetes.taskmanager.cpu=2 \
-Dtaskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots=4 \
-Dresourcemanager.taskmanager-timeout=3600000 \
-Dkubernetes.namespace=sdt-dproc-flink-test \
-Dkubernetes.config.file=/home/devuser/.kube/config \
-Dkubernetes.jobmanager.service-account=flink-service-account
```

After executing above command, I have listed the new pod like below.

```
user@local:~/flink-1.14.4$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dproc-example-flink-cluster-id-68c79bf67-mwh52   1/1     Running   0          1m
```

Then, I have executed the below command to submit example job.

```
user@local:~/flink-1.14.4$ ./bin/flink run --target kubernetes-session \
-Dkubernetes.service-account=flink-service-account \
-Dkubernetes.cluster-id=dproc-example-flink-cluster-id \
-Dkubernetes.namespace=sdt-dproc-flink-test \
-Dkubernetes.config.file=/home/devuser/.kube/config 
examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input /home/user/sometexts.txt --output /tmp/flinksample
```

After a while, I received below logs:

```
2022-03-25 12:38:00,538 INFO  org.apache.flink.kubernetes.KubernetesClusterDescriptor      [] - Retrieve flink cluster dproc-example-flink-cluster-id successfully, JobManager Web Interface: http://10.150.140.248:8081

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1061)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.executeAsync(ContextEnvironment.java:131)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:93)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:1056)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$11(RestClusterClient.java:433)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$1(RestClient.java:476)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:395)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.150.140.248:8081
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1063)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /10.150.140.248:8081
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261)
    ... 8 more
```

I understand from the last part of this error that the JobManager Web Interface URL is wrong because when I check the Kubernetes services, port is different.

```
user@local:~/flink-1.14.4$ kubectl get svc
NAME                                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
dproc-example-flink-cluster-id        ClusterIP      None            <none>        6123/TCP,6124/TCP   6h32m
dproc-example-flink-cluster-id-rest   LoadBalancer   10.97.100.197   <pending>     8081:30976/TCP      6h32m
```

The port should be 30976 rather that 8081.
I have already tried to edit rest.port in flink-conf.yaml with this value and also as parameter from command line. But nothing changed. Always I get this error.

How can I force Flink client to access correct JobManager URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Yang Wang**(danrtsey.wy@gmail.com) from **user@flink.apache.org** has answered my question.Thank you. I am sharing below. I have tried first option related with service expose type as NodePort and I have succeeded to execute job.

---

The root cause might be the LoadBalancer could not really work in your environment. We already have a ticket to track this[1] and will try to get it resolved in the next release.

For now, could you please have a try by adding "-Dkubernetes.rest-service.exposed.type=NodePort" to your session and submission commands?

Maybe you are also interested in the new flink-kubernetes-operator project[2]. It should make it easier to run a Flink application on the K8s.

[1]. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17231 
[2]. https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator

Best,
Yang